# Appfog Django app distribute package error

Tags: python, django, appfog

I'm new to appfog and want to push my django project into the server but it seems that I cannot install distribute package. I have no idea what is preventing the problem, and I cannot find a way to access the shell. Any idea whats going on or how to fix it?

CRASH MESSAGE BELOW

```
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (53K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Stopping Application 'stargazer': OK
Staging Application 'stargazer': OK                                             
Starting Application 'stargazer': ..........
Error: Application [stargazer] failed to start, logs information below.

====> /logs/staging.log <====

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip==1.1 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn

Installing collected packages: gunicorn
  Running setup.py install for gunicorn

    Installing gunicorn_paster script to /tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/bin
    Installing gunicorn script to /tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/bin
    Installing gunicorn_django script to /tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/bin
Successfully installed gunicorn
Cleaning up...
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python==1.2.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
    install a more recent version first, using
    'easy_install -U distribute'.

    (Currently using distribute 0.6.24 (/tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,

and can't be installed while this script is running. Please

install a more recent version first, using

'easy_install -U distribute'.



(Currently using distribute 0.6.24 (/tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg))

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2 in /tmp/d20130318-32281-1qsiluq/staged/python/build/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Have you tried the error suggestion, `easy_install -U distribute`?

Comment: I cannot get into the shell of the app... so I cannot do that.... my requirements.txt already has distribute inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the MySQL-Python requirement to 1.2.3 seems to fix this, as they've already got that version installed.